# Django - KeyError

Tags: python, django, firebase

I don't know why this gives me KeyError at the line: `idtoken=request.session['uid']`, `postCreateEquity` function , this the whole views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import auth
import pyrebase 


config = {
    'apiKey': "AIzaSyCQotYTbJ_W3ezUNc99JGDociFfAIp2-n8",
    'authDomain': "efund-c.firebaseapp.com",
    'databaseURL': "https://efund-c.firebaseio.com",
    'projectId': "efund-c",
    'storageBucket': "efund-c.appspot.com",
    'messagingSenderId': "67104720448"
  } 

firebase= pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
authe = firebase.auth()
database=firebase.database() 

def login(request):
    return render (request,'login.html')

def postlogin(request):
    email=request.POST.get('email')
    passw=request.POST.get('pass')
    try:
       user=authe.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,passw)    #we named auth to authe because we used auth library
    except:
       message="Invalid credentials"
       return render(request,'welcomepage/login.html',{"messg": message})

       print(user['idToken'])
       session_id=user['idToken']
       request.session['uid']=str(session_id)      
    return render (request,'welcomepage/efand-welcome-registered-user.html',{"e":email})


def postlogout(request):
     auth.logout(request)
     return render(request,'welcomepage/login.html')


def signUp(request):
    return render(request,'signup.html')     


def postsignup(request):
    firstName=request.POST.get('signupfirstusername')
    lastName=request.POST.get('signuplastusername')
    email=request.POST.get('signupemail')
    password=request.POST.get('signuppassword')
    vpassw=request.POST.get('signupverifiedpassword')
    birthday=request.POST.get('signupdob')
    country=request.POST.get('signupcountry')
    checkbox=request.POST.get('signupcheckbox')

    user=authe.create_user_with_email_and_password(email,password)

    uid=user['localId']  #this id is unique for everyone

    data={"firstName":firstName,"lastName":lastName ,"birthday":birthday ,"country":country,"checkbox":checkbox}  
    database.child("Users").child(uid).set(data)
    return render(request,'welcomepage/login.html')


def startCampaign(request):
    return render(request,'welcomepage/start-campain-registered-user.html')

def createEquity(request):
    return render(request,'welcomepage/efund-createEquity-registered-user.html')    

def createReward(request):
    return render(request,'welcomepage/efund-createReward-registered-user.html')    

def postCreateEquity(request):


    category=request.POST.get('category')
    duration=request.POST.get('duration')


    highlight=request.POST.get('heighlight')
    imgName=request.POST.get('img')
    investDiscussion=request.POST.get('investDiscussion')
    investTerms=request.POST.get('investterms')
    linkForVideo=request.POST.get('video')
    market=request.POST.get('market')
    name=request.POST.get('name')
    neededMoney=request.POST.get('amountofmoney')
    endDate=request.POST.get('enddate')
    offers=request.POST.get('offers')
    startDate=request.POST.get('startdate')
    summary=request.POST.get('summary')
    team=request.POST.get('team')
    timeline=request.POST.get('timeline')

    idtoken=request.session['uid']
    a= authe.get_account_info(idtoken)
    a=a['users']
    a=a[0]
    a=a['localId']
    print(str(a))

    data={"category":category,"imgName":imgName,"duration":duration,"highlight":highlight,
    "investDiscussion":investDiscussion,"investTerms":investTerms,"linkForVideo":linkForVideo,
    "market":market,"name":name,"neededMoney":neededMoney,"endDate":endDate,"offers":offers,
    "startDate":startDate,"summary":summary,"team":team,"timeline":timeline}




    # idcamp=request.POST.get('signupfirstusername')
    # idcreator=request.POST.get('signupfirstusername')

    database.child('Equity Campaign').child(a).set(data)
    return render(request,'welcomepage/efand-welcome-registered-user.html')
```

Comment: Because '`uid`' is not a key in `request.session`. The error message is rather telling.

Comment: I want to request the session i started in the first function, so i tried to do so using request.session, using uid variable that was stated in the first function , and this worked in some tutorial but not working here and I don't know why

Comment: I think you missed something in your tutorial. You are actually not assigning the 'uid' to the current session in the first function. Maybe check the tutorial again

Comment: I added the whole views.py file, check the code if this will help to find why this error happen.

Comment: try `idtoken=request.session.get('uid',None)` and print the value of idtoken

Comment: It gave me HTTPError , MISSING_ID_TOKEN